# Is it possible to have one MySQL query and depending if a row exists choose INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am working on a project and I am currently stuck on an issue. I have a table which records player visit data. every player has its own unique id and the name of the place they visited, including date of visit and count.

An example row:
`TestUser Server12 2020-10-25 12:00:00 25`

Now speed is part of this problem as I need it to be relevantly fast as I am doing a comparison for up to 70 players. I was thinking a bulk query would be preferable as then it would minimize the execution time significantly, however, the issue is on how to check whether the row is existing in the table for the specific pair`(user and server)`, if not insert a new row, if yes update the current existing row with the current date value following visit count increment`(+1)`

I know of `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY`, however that doesn't work as it uses the primary key to find the row and I use player unique id with the server name.

So my question is, is there any way of doing one query where it would do an insert if the row is non-existent or update the existing row with those two specified columns.

The previous solution I had:

Select statement to check if exists:

```
$"SELECT Count(*) FROM `visited` WHERE playerid='{playerID}' AND server_name='{serverName}'"
```

Afterwards depending from select results do one of these:
INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO visited (playerid, server_name, visit_count, last_visit_date) " +
                    $"VALUES ('{playerID}', '{v}', IFNULL(visit_count,0)+1, '{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}')
```

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE visited SET visit_count=IFNULL(visit_count,0)+1, last_visit_date='{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}' WHERE playerid='{playerID}' AND server_name='{v}'
```

The old solution is really slow, especially if I do per player call.

Comment: Have a look into `UPSERT`. Essentially is a combination of `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

Comment: I will try to REPLACE again, however, INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY and INSERT IGNORE doesn't solve the issue.
Edit:
Replace won't work as well as it needs a primary key. And as mentioned in the post, my goal is to use a unique pair of PlayerId in combination of ServerName.

Comment: *"I know of INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY, however that doesn't work as it uses the primary key to find the row and I use player unique id with the server name."* Have you actually tried that or did you just assume it would only work with primary keys? Cause it works with every unique key. So give it a try.

Comment: Well I did try it, and it used the auto-increment primary key. And as far as I read the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't have a WHERE clause where I could provide the two pairs of columns to use as a comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use the `on duplicate key` syntax. First, you want need a unique (or primary key) constraint on columns `(playerid, server_name)`. Create it if it's not alreay there:

```
 alter table visited 
     add constraint ck_visited_uniq 
     unique (playerid, server_name)
```

Then, you can do:

```
insert into visited (playerid, server_name, visit_count, last_visit_date)
values (?, ?, 1, now())
on duplicate key update 
    visit_count = coalesce(visit_count, 0) + 1, 
    last_visit_date = now()
```

Notes:

- this uses bind parameters (represented by `?`s) rather than concatenating values in the query string
- it seems like you want the current date/time for `last_visit_date`: if so, no need to pass if from your application, you can use built-in function `now()`
- I understand that you want an inital `visit_count` of `1`, that then increments for every hint

Answer (score 0):

I use this way, so I dont have to always relay on Primary ID (key)

```
if exists(select 1 from [{tablename}] where {Where_cmd} )
BEGIN
 update {tablename} set {...} where {Where_cmd};
END  
ELSE 
 INSERT INTO {tablename} (...) Values(...);
```